# Android ListView changing ArrayAdapters

Tags: android

I have a `PullToRefreshListView` that i'm switching `ArrayAdapter`s for depending on what options the user selects. I'm able to get the data to show but for some reason, not able to force a redraw on the `PullToRefreshListView`. So when the list shortens, you can still see the white from when the `PullToRefreshListView` had more data in it, and therefore was longer.

My code is below:

```
if (adapter == null) {
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this.getActivity(), array);

} else {
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(array);
}

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Is there anything else that I can do to refresh the list? I tried searching several other questions on SO including:

[Android - I can't refresh / redraw a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308061/android-i-cant-refresh-redraw-a-listview)

However, it didn't help for my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to post more of the code.  If the list is shortening, and you see white where it used to be, it is not a problem with the ListView refreshing, it's a problem with the ListView's container refreshing.  Does the container have a background set?

Comment: You were right. I was using some open source code and didn't see that until digging in. Case closed.